Changing disk size
I have a dual boot installation with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04 lts, and I need to reduce the size of the partition assigned to Ubuntu. I tried inside Windows but the system disk manager won't allow me to change it. I tried in Ubuntu but the app informs "error dismounting - target is busy".
What solutions are there to solve this?

Windows tools can’t cope with ext3 / ext4, and you can’t resize a mounted partition (and your Ubuntu partition is mounted when you boot into Ubuntu). Use a live USB session to resize using eg gparted. Do please back everything up first (including Windows data) in case it fails and renders your system unbootable - you might conceivably have to reinstall both OS’s.
